# Racket-Mode: Can I evaluate a single form within a given namespace at the REPL?

Tags: emacs, racket, read-eval-print-loop

I'm working at the Racket REPL via `racket-mode` in Emacs, writing code in multiple modules.

Is there a way to execute a single form from a module I'm not currently 'in', in the context of its own module?

For instance:

web.rkt

```
#lang racket
(require "view.rkt")

(define (display-default-view)
  (display (default-view)))
```

view.rkt

```
#lang racket

(provide default-view)

(define default-text "Hello")

(define (default-view)
  (string-append default-text " world"))
```

If I call `racket-run` from `web.rkt` I get a prompt saying `web.rkt>`. If I then run `(display-default-view)` I get "Hello world".

If I then visit `view.rkt` and change the default-text definition to:

```
(define default-text "Hi")
```

and re-evaluate the `default-text` definition, it evaluates fine, and my prompt still says `web.rkt>`.

When I enter `default-text` at the REPL I get "Hi". But when I run `(display-default-view)` I still get "Hello world". I'm presuming this is because all I've done is define a new `default-text` in `web.rkt`.

I'd *expect* to see output change to "Hi world" --- i.e. the behaviour of the `view.rkt` module to be updated. Just like I'd see if `default-text` lived in the `web.rkt` module.

The idea of dynamically re-evaluating single forms at the repl to change program behaviour is terrific, but it seems to not quite work here.

Is there a way to get this behaving as I would expect in racket-mode? Or if not, a mechanism to just enter a module, without running it, so that I can build something myself to do an enter-execute-exit dance?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Originally I thought you were asking how to change a variable in a different namespace in the REPL, but upon re-reading your question, it seems that you would like to evaluate forms in their file's namespace while in that file's buffer. I hope the edit better answers your question (and let me know if I'm still misunderstanding it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated, simpler answer:**

We can evaluate forms in the REPL in the current file's namespace by entering that namespace in the REPL, evaluating these forms, and then re-entering our original namespace. The easiest way to do this seems to be wrapping these forms with functions to enter the current file's namespace (before) and re-entering the original namespace (after) and then sending all of this into the existing Racket-mode code for evaluating forms in the REPL.

We can do this by building a string of our wrapped commands, writing it to a temporary buffer, marking the whole buffer as our region, and then sending it to `racket-send-region`.

```
(defun my-racket-current-namespace-wrapped-commands (buffer-file-string commands)
  "generate string containing commands wrapped with Racket functions to enter
   the current-namespace and then exit it upon finishing"
  (concat "(require (only-in racket/enter enter!))"
          "(enter! (file "
          buffer-file-string
          "))"
          commands
          "(enter! #f)"))

(defun my-racket--send-wrapped-current-namespace (commands)
  "sends wrapped form of commands to racket-send-region function via a temporary buffer"
  (let ((buffer-file-string (prin1-to-string buffer-file-name)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert
       (my-racket-current-namespace-wrapped-commands buffer-file-string commands))
      (mark-whole-buffer)
      (racket-send-region (point-min) (point-max)))))

(defun my-racket-send-region-current-namespace (start end)
  "send region to REPL in current namespace"
  (interactive "r")
  (unless (region-active-p)
    (user-error "No region"))
  (let ((commands (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
    (my-racket--send-wrapped-current-namespace commands)))

(defun my-racket-send-last-sexp-current-namespace ()
  "send last sexp to REPL in current namespace"
  (interactive)
  (let ((commands (buffer-substring (my-racket--repl-last-sexp-start)
                                    (point))))
    (my-racket--send-wrapped-current-namespace commands)))

(defun my-racket--repl-last-sexp-start ()
    "get start point of last-sexp
     permanent (and slightly simplified) copy of racket mode's last-sexp-start private function"
  (save-excursion
    (progn
      (backward-sexp)
      (if (save-match-data (looking-at "#;"))
          (+ (point) 2)
        (point)))))
```

These functions should mostly be version agnostic - they only depend on `racket-send-buffer` (which seems likely to remain in future versions).

---

Edit 1: *(Note - this does not seem to work as is for newer versions of Racket-mode. This worked as of the April 01, 2018 release, but newer versions seem to have refactored some of the internals this relied on. In almost all cases, the code above is preferable.)*

Sorry, I believe that I originally misunderstood the question. It looks like you mean executing the command straight from view.rkt without having to manually change the namespace in the REPL. I didn't see any built-in functionally in racket-mode that does this, but it's not too hard to write an Elisp wrapper around this process. The following imports in `enter!`, switches to the current buffer's file's namespace, sends the code in the region, and then switches back to the original namespace. The code used is very similar to what racket-mode uses for `racket-send-region` and `racket-send-last-sexp`.

```
(defun my-racket-send-region-current-namespace (start end)
  "Send the current region to the Racket REPL as that namespace"
  (interactive "r")
  (when (and start end)
    (racket-repl t)
    (racket--repl-forget-errors)
    (let ((proc (racket--get-repl-buffer-process)))
      (with-racket-repl-buffer
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (process-mark proc))
          (insert ?\n)
          (set-marker (process-mark proc) (point))))
      (comint-send-string proc "(require (only-in racket/enter enter!))")
      (comint-send-string proc
                          (concat "(enter! (file "
                                  (prin1-to-string buffer-file-name)
                                  "))"))
      (comint-send-string proc "\n"))
    (racket--repl-show-and-move-to-end)
    (racket--send-region-to-repl start end)
    (let ((proc (racket--get-repl-buffer-process)))
      (with-racket-repl-buffer
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (process-mark proc))
          (insert ?\n)
          (set-marker (process-mark proc) (point))))
      (comint-send-string proc "(enter! #f)")
      (comint-send-string proc "\n"))))


(defun my-racket-send-last-sexp-current-namespace ()
  (interactive)
  (my-racket-send-region-current-namespace
   (save-excursion
     (backward-sexp)
     (if (save-match-data (looking-at "#;"))
         (+ (point) 2)
       (point)))
   (point)))
```

Note that if you're using this frequently, this function could probably use more error checking (e.g. the import of `require/enter` will clobber any previous definition of `enter!`).

I've also kept the original text below about how to manually switch namespaces in the REPL, in case it helps.

---

You can use the function `enter!` in the `racket/enter` module to switch namespaces to modify definitions in the namespace of the other file.

After calling `racket-run` in web.rkt, you could do the following in the REPL:

```
(display-default-view) ;; output is "Hello world"
(require racket/enter)
(enter! "view.rkt")    ;; change namespace to view.rkt
(define default-text "Hi")
(enter! #f)            ;; return to original namespace
(display-default-view) ;; output is "Hi world"
```

See the [Racket documentation for more details on interactive module loading](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/interactive.html).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's exactly what I was getting at.

Comment: It's a great suggestion but unfortunately the result isn't what I hoped. The form executes in the `"view.rkt"` namespace, but when I re-enter the "web.rkt" namespace, `display-default-view` still  returns "Hello world". The new form hasn't been re-bound.
This behaviour seems curiously different from the standard REPL behaviour.

Comment: There was a bug in my code. The Racket region-send function I used fails if the region isn't active (which isn't likely to be the case for send-last-sexp). I swapped it out with a different racket-mode function (racket--send-region-to-repl) that doesn't do this check. Did you have issues with both functions or just the send-last-sexp code? If it was just the latter, it should be fixed now.

Comment: Hmm, your solution seems really good, but there's still a problem for me. Looking at it more closely, I think we're at cross-purposes because you're working with an older version of racket-mode. I had to update your snippet to use `(get-buffer-process racket--repl-buffer-name)` instead of `(racket--get-repl-buffer-process)`, but it looks like there have also been broader changes to the command model. Sending commands to the repl has changed quite a bit, and this solution doesn't seem to work with the new model.

Comment: Good catch - my racket-mode was about a year out-of-date. I gave a quick look at the new racket-mode code; it doesn't seem like it should take too much alteration to what I wrote before to make it work. Nonetheless, I've revised my answer with what I believe is a simpler (and more version-agnositic) solution. We just enter a temporary buffer, write the code to enter the namespace, the commands we want to run, and the code to re-enter the original namespace. Then we select the whole temporary buffer as the region and send that to racket-send-region to let racket-mode handle the rest.

Comment: Nice one! It works for me now although I still had to change the racket--get-repl-buffer-process call. Awesome stuff and I've learned a lot. Thanks!

Comment: A friendly tip: Emacs Lisp doesn't have modules, so people use a prefix naming convention: (1) `racket-x` means a **"public"** function that (a) you may call, but (b) don't define your own functions with that prefix! Make up your own prefix (your initials is a common convention for personal code). (2) `racket--x` (two hyphens) means a **"private"** function you shouldn't call or depend on working the same or even existing in the future.

Comment: It's your copy of Emacs so of course you can do whatever you want. It's just, I'm allowed to add new things to the `racket-` "namespace", and, do anything at all in the `racket--` "namespace". That might break your things someday.

Comment: @GregHendershott Those are good points. I was writing this answer from a proof-of-concept perspective, rather than as a permanent tool, but I completely agree with you about the prefixes to the function names. I've edited my answer to add an additional prefix "my" (and to permanently define a version of the last-sexp-start private function.)